# Will the java Splitter result list ever be empty?

Tags: java, guava, is-empty

I am trying to split a string using [Splitter](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) class. For example:

```
List<String> resultList = Splitter.on("|").splitToList(stringToSplit);
```

My question is: can `resultList` ever be empty?

I cannot think of any cases that it would be empty. But if I directly use `resultList.get(0)`, it seems buggy. Can I directly call `resultList.get(0)` without worries?

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems buggy"?

Comment: It's not buggy. If you give empty string, then you can call `get(0)` that returns empty string

Comment: I mean, we used to check whether a list is empty before we index it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that depends on how you configure your splitter instance. Here you have to very similar examples, both as input take an empty string.

First case uses "raw" splitter returns a list with only one element -- an empty string:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnOneEmptyStringForRegularSplitter() {
    //given
    String input = "";
    Splitter splitter = Splitter.on(',');
    //when
    List<String> result = splitter.splitToList(input);
    //then
    assertThat(result).containsOnly("");
}
```

In the second example the input is the same, but splitter is additionally configured to omit empty strings from a resulting list, which as a result returns an empty list:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnOneEmptyStringForCustomized() {
    //given
    String input = "";
    Splitter splitter = Splitter.on(',').omitEmptyStrings();
    //when
    List<String> result = splitter.splitToList(input);
    //then
    assertThat(result).isEmpty();
}
```

The behavior is [documented](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html):

> For separator-based splitters that **do not use `omitEmptyStrings`**, an input string containing n occurrences of the separator naturally yields an iterable of size n + 1. So if the separator does not occur anywhere in the input, a single substring is returned containing the entire input. Consequently, **all splitters split the empty string to `[""]` (note: even fixed-length splitters)**.

`Splitter` has couple more options you could configure and change the result base on that.

In your case, if you only use `Splitter.on("|")` without any additional options, you're guaranteed to always have at least one value in resulting list.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this without checking if empty or not

```
resultList.stream().findFirst().orElseGet(null)
```

this will return the first object in your list otherwise it will return null

Answer (score -1):

Base on code of the method `Splitter#splitToList` [here](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html#line.407),
It will return an empty ArrayList in case the given string could not be split

(In your case, it happens if the string does not contain "|")

```
407  public List<String> splitToList(CharSequence sequence) {
408    checkNotNull(sequence);
409
410    Iterator<String> iterator = splittingIterator(sequence);
411    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
412
413    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
414      result.add(iterator.next());
415    }
416
417    return Collections.unmodifiableList(result);
418  }
```

Thus, you have to ensure the result is not empty or an IndexOutOfBoundsException would be thrown when calling `resultList.get(0)`

Comment: "will return an empty ArrayList in case the given string could not be split" I may be misunderstanding you, in which case please correct me if I am wrong. But if I understand you correctly you would expect `Splitter.on("x").splitToList("ab");` to return empty list since `ab` can't be split on `x`. But that is not the case. If string can't be split list will contain one element, the original string itself so it will contain 1 element.

Comment: @Pshemo That is the case. What i'm trying to tell you that is, when string can't be split the list can't contain any element. Take a look at the statement `List<String> resultList = Splitter.on("|").splitToList(stringToSplit);`, the result from `splitToList` will be assigned to `resultList`. Thus, it will be an empty list in that case

Comment: In that case I am afraid you may be mistaken. If in that example we will assign to `stringToSplit` value which can't be split on `|` like `String stringToSplit = "abc"` then `List<String> resultList` will contain list with one element: `"abc"`, so it will not be empty.

Answer (score -2):

how about checking that stringToSplit contains "|" before call Splitter.on.splitToList